# How to change the wordpress file structure?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to change wordpress file structure from this:

```
/www
└── /site.com
    ├── /wp-admin
    ├── /wp-content
    └── /wp-includes
```

to this:

```
/www
├── /cdn.site.com
│   └── /content        #renamed wp-content folder
└── /site.com
    └── /subfolder
        ├── /admin        #renamed wp-admin folder
        └── /includes     #renamed wp-includes folder
```

without plugins or core changes?

Comment: Renaming all those directories would take a lot of effort as I believe wp-includes is hardcoded. You would also need to remake those changes if you ever update. Are you just trying to hide the path in the source so people cant find out you're using wordpress? You can use URL rewrite to do that and there are plenty of wordpress plugins that will hide the fact that its wordpress as well.

Comment: I'm trying to move my content files, such js, css and img, to subdomen and also hide wp-admin. Thx you for answer.